# Return a SUM from multiple sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula that returns values from multiple sheets under certain criteria and provides the sum.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&B17&" "&Year&"*'!C:C"),"Total",INDIRECT("'"&B17&" "&Year&"*'!Z:Z")),0))
```

I am looking to return a value that is correlated to Total, but since there are multiple Totals on each page I get back the sum of them all. I only need one Total (that is listed as 100%) from each sheet rather than all of them.

[image]

Comment: Sample data with expected results will be usefull here. See [ask] a question with a [mcve].

Comment: @JvdV I have added a image that shows all the columns that are a "Total". Since I am using the formula across multiple sheets, I can't use a simple VLOOKUP to return only one value.

Comment: Unclear to me. You need to return only the latest total in a sheet? Sum these latest totals from each sheet in one grand total?

Comment: Yes! In this case I want 52371 + (98437 which is the total on the next sheet). But with my current formula I get in return the sum of every total on the sheet which is around 5,000,000

Comment: But what makes that you don't want 1920872. You are leaving a lot open for guesswork.

Comment: If you notice the % of Total it is at 3668%. I am not sure why this is added to the file in general, but I am only looking for the total that corelates to 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(SUMIFS(INDIRECT("'"&B17&" "&Year&"*'!Z:Z"),INDIRECT("'"&B17&" "&Year&"*'!C:C"),B19,INDIRECT("'"&B17&" "&Year&"*'!AA:AA"),"100%")/COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("'"&B17&" "&Year&"*'!C:C"),B19,INDIRECT("'"&B17&" "&Year&"*'!AA:AA"),"100%"),0))
```

This is the solution I came up with. Changed to SUMIFS to make criteria more detailed searching for "Total" (which is B19) and "100%". Then divide by COUNTIFS using the same criteria as SUMIFS since each sheet has different amount of Total rows

Answer (score 0):

Linking spreadsheets is inherently fragile.
If you do it, then to minimise fragility:

- use named ranges for your target cells.
- bring them to your consolidating spreadsheet as single numbers - then sum them there.